# String overflowing when concatting

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program packer but i always fail because when i concat three strings(one contains prefix of source, one contains executable content, other contains suffix of source) content overflows into suffix. Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ProgramPacker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string prefix = @"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text; 
using System.IO; 

namespace ProgramPacker 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static string inside = @" + "\"";
        static string suffix = "\";\n" + @"static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            string temp = Path.GetRandomFileName() +" + "\"" + @".exe" + "\"" + @";
            BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Create));
            sw.Write(inside);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(temp); 
        } 
    } 
}";
    public string code = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open));
        byte[] data = new byte[br.BaseStream.Length];
        br.Read(data, 0, (int)br.BaseStream.Length);
        br.Close();
        string inside = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(data);
        code = string.Concat(prefix, string.Concat(inside, suffix));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write(code);
        CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler compile = cs.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters();
        param.GenerateInMemory = false;
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        param.GenerateExecutable = true;
        param.OutputAssembly = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/a.exe";
        param.WarningLevel = 4;
        CompilerResults comp = compile.CompileAssemblyFromSource(param, code);
        foreach (CompilerError error in comp.Errors)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Line + " " + error.Column + " "  + error.ErrorText);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(comp.PathToAssembly);
        MessageBox.Show("Finish!");
    }
}
```

}

It outputs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text; 
using System.IO; 

namespace ProgramPacker
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static string inside = @"?ãÎoüoy±ôãøÿ?ÿQÔh¦Rt!?^ÿyóë=G:Fÿ»??¿Ç/}òKÿ?úõßû3õMù?c·?Äûòëoª?À_Û>LÖïá^öÿ·õ©üüòcÊ?ª??÷Ô?î:^È¯ÏäG¶?ù ?ñË?oñëy:ôã7??ò@ÚyN?w¿=?ëÆ÷ëÛßTëºÓ»yßüø]áå{ö/àïªêL©Oÿ;ú5rù% ä¸?1)Ï?¥?y®ÿ]0QL8û×ÖGòów±?øÿÃ¨ü[?ª~éá¿ÿó£üüJ~Ü¹
Êw¡h??/?úçeñÈ_?¿?ü½L^ywü7?,ùÅû¿ß£ó÷w?É~Ç????ê?ÿQÌyç¿??¹Cö×vZ__>?? ûïx?_ü"õ!ì; ;ùõåÇ?ú3*­¿   @ÿV?èÿ¿Ë??/½P¶y?â¡??ùñÿÑæä/A¶_ò?v??ÿ?ÿQtÄx÷w?O'N?u$ÿk÷U«yÆò?£.Y?ùw(?ßÔ6ÿ]2ÿeUÆò¿?Ø¶ö·ßO~ü#*y£Jæ·Ä w yóYëï´
õ}y¡ä¨ù÷YPdú?Z©Óé¼R?æg?ÀSyàì¬½Éÿ­ûÁ?ym>ut?ÿA??>?¿[ôçF ê´)9ß9xÿ£¿?
åùïyí ÁTlù
-ùñ?Òÿ·!·
E?£üO5÷]çºy?7Áè¿?Zô?(å§
#ü¥úõ®?o«âû]0Èßä7¿à??¿õ?d?Ñµ;Jü_K?úAMìT>Àü1mR0sâ¿ê¨õ{äö×ó??¿.úÿõ½Eä?ÔïÿÎÿ±³v'ÿûìw ?»oÃø1±WtB
É¡wì&øuå£Îÿ?Éw?|úWÿ=ö÷_ÿ·?y®YWöwû¿ßß?Öe'û?%?yß/×Àî-yÿ.?8åóù?ûÇÚ6ÿÂßøï?Áàï?{8Zy?¿Å5yø    ÇpÏ9=ó»üÑ>Õ?Èÿ?Y¿,?ëÿ?Êçÿì_}E?÷Ûú|î$ò÷ø}Jÿ^Êtò¿?@á|ò{Ø`<ªÿQ?QLæ½õo)¿ü&¿áÂÿ¼ó¿_÷7yMå8)¿Ùo'¿õ±üü=~#LÚ¿ó§¢Ë÷üO?Æ?å÷WJÍ$¾¸øW?A?Òÿ(09Áÿà³_ëÿù3l?SWYµßô÷¤~?ÀG¿ñ
??Às%ÍyÑ;Ò¸!ÿ?_Iÿ¼¼í/Ôrö
?T´ôÑùyÇ¹ßE~üV?ñ¿C~VßùuÿG   X8|._¼Å_:Æü-?îü:?øì?|W  ¤ÃÓW01?$å×?Û#ùIÿû·1:4û½ü._y^òÙNó?º1?ßIÍ?ÿ¿ß_~|ÖùX?@?në_B?¡µ~_×ãÿhãèïØÏßì¡yïôk_y;HÿÛyÿàâ/sÀ??? $ìw0Jüßü«@?ûo?¿îËX
´úÏ?Æ?Y>øçÿFpyÅÿèËöyK¡²Ì`}ù½Ò¿íÿÀñn"?Í?ëOëi»ò¹Î~çÿ?_òüîÿh£ôáêDøÏÿ¶?ç·fy ÄúçÿÖÿ?yÿ?¿?ã0ÿ¿Ë÷åå?ÿQ|ü/ü9¿?÷×Hè×ÉÏ#õ??æ?ÿâ?x?ß?5µ}~Øy¾ß^øè{¿
y{íü;Òÿ¿óú7¤¡î?»    yû?ÀÓøiP?ÿÀ_ôK?Gëªíá@??ú%íwS×ñ¿¨#Û¦ÿÿÛªy\]¼÷Z~yR~ü¶ÿ£hû???ÇãÿQVèÿ©?÷{O?Gë¬ ??¡ø\«L` æcëí¿ ½?»?ü?oë¼Ätÿ>ò÷£­_¯ÖiÄ?¯ÿÓ¿÷Ï?(c¦äàéûèó?ü£´çÕè4üy_
r?qÆ¿ø'?KÿÀ_ó×xùkÔ¿FõkÌ~õ¯1y5Ú_ã'??n~â×¨~å¯ñkü»¿Æø×Ø±ÿÿ5~?_ã7ø5~Í_ã?Z4ÔrñkL~ò×¸?5Òßûÿ??ñïñnQ¦?yYÕò³vÇ;¥ùrZÍ?åÅg}õæÙöÁGiÓfËYVVËü³®óæ£ßãè7NgM?/&åuJrustInfo>
</assembly>
; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Any help?

EDIT: **Why is everyone down-voting? I just asked a question.**

Comment: And this listing is supposed to be an example output?

Comment: What is an example 'inside' that you are using? Perhaps the quotes aren't escaped properly?

Comment: inside is a file that can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54262149/FileOrder.exe

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, see OP for output.

Comment: btw, this app feels a little fishy, writing an internal exe to a temp file and then executing it? Trying to trojan something are we?

Comment: Why would you think you can concatenate a string with *binary* content? Binary content (as in executable file content) isn't suitable content to be assigned to a string. (It's like trying to put chicken noodle soup in between two slices of plain old sandwich bread - it ain't gonna work when you try to pick it up, because they're not compatible for use that way.)

Comment: @payo LOL, i'm just trying to compress files effectively using GZip so everyone can open it without WinRAR/equivalent(who doesn't have it?). I just removed zipping code to see if it's working.

Comment: @Ken White well, i didn't know that! But i convert binary data to a string using Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(). i think it should work.

Comment: Not if you don't have a string to convert. `Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes()` only works if you're converting a *string* from one encoding to another; it doesn't magically convert non-string data into strings. (You can't add food coloring to chicken soup and have it magically stay between the bread slices.)

Comment: :ifail: I meant Encoding.UTF7.GetString().

Comment: **We aren't here to discuss the fishy-ness of the question.** There's nothing malicious in his question, and packaging code or writing code that evolves is a technique that's used in some occasions. Please note that packaging code *does not override any security boundaries*, it actually depends on the system security where he is allowed to save it to and whether it can be executed out-of-bounds (eg. NX bit). So, I see no reason why we should get rid of his question. Only the executable that he linked could be an edge case, please don't run it without thoroughly checking it...

Comment: @user1286744 I've edited my answer to use Base64, plz check

Comment: @everyone Okay, i just fixed it! Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: **Users are more than free to vote their conscience**.  And if a user believes that the OP is trying to craft malicious code, they are more than welcome to comment for clarification and downvote.  Its up to OP to explain, or decline to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a problem of representation, one that you're not likely to fix with your code as-is.

However, you can choose to follow a similar approach with just minor modifications (which don't actually compress your program much at all).

1. Remove the `@` from the definition of the string `inside`. This is one of the causes of your problems.
2. You can't just put a BELL character or NUL character in-line in your string, instead write out their unicode escape sequences:

   ```
   string inside = String.Concat(
       data.Select(b => String.Format(@"\u{0:X4}", b)));
   ```
3. Now, in your `suffix` code, reinterpret your `inside` string as characters which you cast to bytes:

   ```
   sw.Write(inside.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray()); // hardly efficient
   ```

I was able to use these modifications and successfully "pack" and execute the following:

```
C:\temp>type hello.cs 
using System;
class M {
static void Main(string[] args) {
System.IO.File.Create("hello.world");
}
}

C:\temp>csc hello.cs 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\temp>pack.exe hello.exe 
3584 bytes

C:\temp>a.exe

C:\temp>dir *.world 
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is AABD-D663

 Directory of C:\temp

 03/22/2012  16:36                 0 hello.world
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  279,351,762,944 bytes free
```

Comment: According to the spec, any unicode character is allowed in a verbatim string (except, of course, `"`, which is always represented by `""`).  Shouldn't that therefore include BELL and NUL?

Comment: @phoog: I was unsuccessful in getting those to compile.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use bare UTF7 or UTF8 strings, use Base64 encoding instead.

```
// given: byte[] data = new byte[...]
string inside = System.Convert.ToBase64String(data);
code = string.Concat(prefix, string.Concat(inside, suffix));    

// in your target code
sw.Write(System.Convert.FromBase64String(inside));
```

Comment: @user1286744: this is way simpler than mine, talk about tunnel vision on my part! You won't need to escape anything with the Base64 encoded data. I would take this over mine, any day (and twice on Sunday).

Answer (score 1):

Better use CodeCompileUnit to generate C# code from a C# program:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecompileunit.aspx

You can also use this to compile the generated ATS into an assembley.

Or parse your template parts from files. That would make the code much more readable.

Comment: Well, problem here is that it overflows when i concat three strings. But good advices, i'll probably use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just express executable binary code as a C# string without escaping it.  At least you need to replace any occurrences of the double-quote character (`'"'`) with a sequence of two double-quote characters.  I would be very surprised if that's the only problem you encounter, however.

Note that the string might contain control characters that cause the screen to display the string in a garbled way, but that wouldn't necessarily cause the code containing that string to compile improperly.  For example, if you have a verbatim string containing a backspace (`"stac{backspace}koverflow"`, say), the character after the backspace would overwrite the character before the backspace, so viewing the string on the screen would give an inaccurate representation of its contents (`"stakoverflow"`).  The compiler would presumably see the full 14-character string including the backspace.

Comment: I tried payo's code which escapes quotes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1286744 As I said, I would have been surprised if it had.  I added a couple of thoughts to the answer.